# Is it possible to get `www.mydomain.com/app` to point to `www.myapp.heroku.com`?

Tags: heroku, dns

I have `www.myapp.heroku.com` and domain name `www.mydomain.com`.

Is it possible to have `www.mydomain.com/app` point to `www.myapp.heroku.com`?

Googling seems to only yield how to get `www.mydomain.com` to point to `www.myapp.heroku.com`.  I can't find anything about forward slashes.

Comment: What are you serving on the rest of the domain, and how?

Comment: Short answer: it depends.  Specifically, it depends on what what your response is to SLaks' comment!!

Comment: SLaks and Stephen: on the rest of the domain I'm pointing to a squarespace landing page.  Is this doable?

Comment: I found an alternative solution.  Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

Try it with HTACCESS (If unknown create a blank file in your base directory and rename it to: .htaccess

Now add:

```html
RewriteEngine on 

Redirect /app http://www.app.yourdomain.com
```

Just tested it, will work (if your provider supports htaccess url forwarding)

Good Luck